# Recursively list files containing an underscore in the file name

Tags: files, recursive

I have a large directory with tons of files and subdirectories in it. Is there a way to recursively search through all of these files and subdirectories and print out a list of all files containing an underscore (_) in their file name?

Comment: `find . -name '*_*'`

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! If you post this as an answer instead of a comment I will mark is as correct.

Comment: I'll let you answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name '*_*'
```

Thanks to Stéphane Chazelas as noted in the comments above!